# Paypal -multiple transactions refund -node js - async issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, paypal

I am using PayPal payment in my React application, where I am trying to make a refund for users who choose to withdraw from the tournament. And I used to perform refund at my backend node js.

well, coming to the issue. I am not able to perform the refund when I have more than one refunds to make.
The following is the code I have used to make refunds to multiple transactions. This is the SDK I use
https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-NodeJS-SDK.

For async, I have referred this blog https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-in-loops/

I have no errors in log.

```
app.post('/tournament/users/withdraw',VerifyRoute,(request, response)=>{
    const {withDrawUsers,tournament_id,registration_fee,payer_info}=request.body;
    ....
    ....
    to_withdraw.map(async(withDrawUsers)=>{
            function client() {
                let clientId = "xyz";
                let clientSecret = "abc";
                let environment = new checkoutNodeJssdk.core.SandboxEnvironment(clientId, clientSecret);
                return  new checkoutNodeJssdk.core.PayPalHttpClient(environment);
            }
            async function refundOrder(captureId,amount ,debug=false) {
                try {
                    const request = new checkoutNodeJssdk.payments.CapturesRefundRequest(captureId);
                    request.requestBody({
                            "amount": {
                            "value": amount,
                            "currency_code": "USD"
                            }
                    });
                    const response = await client().execute(request);
                }
                catch (error) {
                    errorLogger.error("Error refunding the order "+error);
                }
            }   
                (async() => await refundOrder(withDrawUsers.transaction_id,(registration_fee*(withDrawUsers.noOfUsers)).toString(),false))();
        })
    });   
});
```